# Adding appendix "chapters," without sections, in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have a document with two appendices, and I would like the appendices to appear in the table of contents but without the sections of each appendix appearing.  For example, I would like the table of contents to contain something like the following:

```
Appendices ................ 100
  A  First Appendix ....... 101
  B  Second Appendix ...... 110

Bibliography .............. 130
```

I've tried toying with the appendix package, but haven't been able to get the result I'd like.  Any help would be most appreciated.  Just for comparison, right now my code is

```
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{First Appendix}
    \chapter{Second Appendix}
\end{appendices}
```

Using `\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}` the table of contents looks like

```
Appendices  .............. 100

A  First Appendix ........ 101
   A.1  First section .... 101
   A.2  Second section ... 102

B  Second Appendix ....... 110
   B.1  First section .... 110
   B.2  Second section ... 113

Bibliography ............. 120
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate; I know there are several questions regarding appendices and the table of contents, but I didn't see any that were quite like my question.

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}

  \chapter{Second appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
\end{appendices}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\addtotoc{Bibliography}{\bibliography{bibliography}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to change the value of `tocdepth` just for the appendices. It's probably not necessary to reset it afterwards, since the appendices are at the end.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}

  \chapter{Second appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the appendices appear as if they were sections, you can change the meaning of `\l@chapter` and of `\l@section` in the same vein:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First section}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
  \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}
\makeatother
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}

  \chapter{Second appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}

\backmatter

\chapter{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

I used `\backmatter` and `\chapter{Bibliography}` just to show the result. Use your own method.

[image]

Comment: @egreg Ok, I have tried this code. Several problems appear. Please take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187205/create-an-appendix-with-sections-for-extra-tables-and-a-appendix-with-sections  Thanks.

Comment: @egreg: This is a very nice solution. But in my PDF viewer (okular) the navigation bar does not list my appendices under the entry "Appendices" but rather on the same level. I guess this is due to the fact that every appendix is a \chapter. Do you have any idea how make them appear under the entry "Appendix"? (The ToC lists everything correctly, as in your example.)

Comment: @eins6180 Look at the documentation of the `bookmark` package. It's a new question, anyway.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't immediately see how the `bookmark` package could be of help. But I asked a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280829). Maybe you could have look?

Comment: This solution doesn't work well for me if I insert `\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}},addtotoc={1,chapter,1,Statement,p1}]{statement}` line before the following line: `\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}`. *Statement* is displayed as a `B1` in the table of contents (`C` instead `B1` is expected).

Comment: I get `chapter@@section section@@subsection` in the toc instead an the chapters are still on the same level as chapters before appendix. I use scrreprt.

Comment: @sivizius Sorry, but `scrbook` is quite a different beast. This deserves a fresh question.