# Create an Appendix with sections for extra tables, and a Appendix with sections for demonstrations

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, preamble

I would like to include an "Annex" chapter named "Anexos", which would have several sections, in which extra tables would be exposed.

In addition, demonstrations would be included in an "Appendix" chapter, named "Apéndices", that would have also have several sections.

Here I show it:

[image]

Tables from Annex A and should be named as A.1, A.2, A.3. Tables form Annex B should be named as B.1, B.2, B.3 and so on.

Equations form Appendix A and B should be named A.1, A.2 ... and B.1, B.2 ... respectively.

Would it be a possible way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have tried the answer posted in [Adding appendix "chapters," without sections, in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172496/adding-appendix-chapters-without-sections-in-table-of-contents?rq=1) by @egreg.

Several problems appear.

So, having the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\begingroup
\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
\let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}

\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}
\section{Q}

(All the info)

\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

But, the result in the index is this:

[image]

The problem is that I would like to be said: **Apéndices**, instead of **Appendices**

**First question**: Could it be possible to change **Appendices** for **Apéndices** in the index ?

**Second problem**: The result is that the left page represented has also the word **Appendices**. Could it also be changed?

[image]

**Third problem**: As I said in the first image before the **EDIT**, I would like to include a "Annex" for extra tables and a "Appendix" for demonstrations. 
The "Appendix" part has been achieved except for the two above problems.

**Third question:** So, how could the upper code be modified in order to include a **Anexos** part ?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\parindent 1 true cm
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,super]{natbib} 
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}                                        
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter .\ #1}{}}             
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection .\ #1}{}}
\lhead{\nouppercase}
\rhead{\nouppercase}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\sf \leftmark}}                             
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\sf \rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{}                                                
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}                                           
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}                                                         
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}                                
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\captionsetup{font={small}}
\begin{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine the relevant commands before starting an `appendices` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexos}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\begingroup
\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
\let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}

\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}
\section{Q}

(All the info)

\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}

\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Ap\'endices}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Ap\'endices}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Ap\'endice}

\begin{appendices}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
\begingroup
\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
\let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}

\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}
\section{Q}

(All the info)

\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

---

A better strategy, that avoids all that code in the document, is to define a new environment based on `appendices`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{varappendices}[2]% #1 is the global name, #2 the single name
 {\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}{#2}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
    \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
  }%
  \appendices
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}}
 {\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
  \endappendices}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{varappendices}{Anexos}{Anexo}

\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}
\section{Q}

(All the info)

\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}
\section{Q}

(All the info)

\end{varappendices}

\begin{varappendices}{Ap\'endices}{Ap\'endice}

\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}
\section{Q}

(All the info)

\end{varappendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg.I have tried both strategies. The rest of the document is ok, except for the index, in which it still appears **Appendices** instead of **Apéndices**, and **Appendices** instead of  **Anexos** : See: https://www.mediafire.com/?j9p5420vxal0l11

Comment: @DavidC. I have fixed it, adding also the redefinition of `\appendixtocname`

Comment: @egreg.Thanks, but this solution makes: https://www.mediafire.com/?6vwlf2ptc7k7rd3  Would it be possible to make **Apéndices** start with A. (and the next) B. etc. instead of starting with B. (and the next) C. ?

Comment: @DavidC. I get the Apéndices starting with A.

Comment: @egregThank you very much, It finally was solved. Could you please take a look at a special table environment at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187287/environment-for-changing-citations-in-tables

Comment: @egreg.I have just noticed that there is a problem with this code when compiling: This code generates [this](https://www.mediafire.com/?vg2vqyco457vm3g), where in the index there is no specification in "sections": In the index, beneath each Appendix or Annex, there is no A.1., A.2., etc, even though in the code, after making `\chapter{Demostración momento cuadrupolar}`, (and the information) I specified a section:  `\section{Obtención}`. How should the upper code be modified in order that sections A.1, A.2 appear in the index ? Thanks

Comment: Change `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` to `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` (I changed it in the code)

Comment: @egreg.Thank you very much, It worked. I am trying to make superscript citations only for tables. Could you please glimpse http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187287/environment-for-changing-citations-in-tables?noredirect=1#comment433661_187287 ? Thanks