# \AtBeginEnvironment adds spurious spaces to .toc when using \addtocontents

Tags: appendices, etoolbox

I'm using `scrartcl` and am trying to move the appendices in the toc one level up so that they are formatted as if they where a subsection instead of a section.

I've adapted my solution from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187205/create-an-appendix-with-sections-for-extra-tables-and-a-appendix-with-sections) question and my current MWE (min.tex) looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[page]{appendix}  % better appendices: \begin{appendices}
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % needed for code below (\AtBeginEnvironment)
\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \addappheadtotoc             % add Appendices to toc
    \makeatletter
    \addtocontents{toc}{%        % move appendix sections one level up in toc
        \begingroup              % make sure we reset section level redefinition after appendices
        \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
        \let\protect\l@subsection\protect\l@subsubsection}}
\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}  % reset section level redefinition

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\section{Variablen}
\section{Tabellen}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

When compiling with lualatex the second time to get the table of contents, I get the following error:

```
) (./min.toc

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 ...tsline {section}{\numberline {A}Variablen}{1}
```

Looking at min.toc, it is clear why. There are spourious spaces added in the commands

```
\begingroup \let \l @section\l @subsection \let \l @subsection\l @subsubsection
```

which should read

```
\begingroup \let \l@section\l@subsection \let \l@subsection\l@subsubsection
```

When I add the `\let` commands just after `\begin{appendices}` it works fine. So my suspicion is, that `\AtBeginEnvironment` is adding those spaces. I'd rather like to keep this in the preamble and not put it in the main document. Is there a way to fix this?

### Update

The formatting problem described below is fixed imho quite more elegantly in the accepted answer than my edit here. I suggest to use that. But I'll leave my fix for the record.

---

The solution from the answer below and from the above question with the fix in the comments by cgnieder has inconsistency problems with the "Appendices" heading of the `appendix` package. To adapt it to the formatting of sections used in `scrartcl`, the command `\@sec@pppage` has to be renwed (modified from the [`appendix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@sec@pppage}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{4ex}%
  \@afterindentfalse
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   % the following line was changed from the original
   \usekomafont{disposition} \usekomafont{section} \appendixpagename%
   \markboth{}{}\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
  \fi
  \nobreak
  \vskip 3ex
  \@afterheading
}
\makeatother
```

This code might be a bit overkill, but it works. Unfortunately, my LaTeX programming skills are not quite where they could be. Maybe someone has a better solution?

Comment: I am not sure, but adding `\begingroup` inside an argument without `\endgroup` does not look very healthy. And you mean 'pushing' down the appendix, since for `scrartcl` appendix entries are sections, subsections is just one level below

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :) You just need a `\makeatletter` before `\AtBeginEnvironment` and a `\makeatother` after all the patching is done

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I do close the group in `\AtEndEnvironment`. If I don't do it at the end of the `appendices` environment, the bibliography or any other section that comes after is also pushed down.

Comment: @cgnieder: That works nicely! I have to read up on those two commands. Could you convert is to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @justibus see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Comment: @justibus: Changed the solution

Comment: @justibus: There's no need in fiddling about the KOMA - Script internal setup of environments/commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution without `\AtBeginEnvironment` and grouping, by slight redefinition of `appendices` environment and letting temporarily `\section` being the same as `\subsection`

**Edit**

There is already a `subappendices` environment by the package `appendix`. Its perhaps better to use that environment instead of hacking the `appendices` environment. However, this solution shows both ways.

The fact, that `\begin{appendices} introduces a strange,`\part`- like heading for 
the appendix is due to the`[page]`option. Removing that and adding a more appropiate`\section*` like heading cures this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{appendix}  % better appendices: \begin{appendices}
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % needed for code below (\AtBeginEnvironment)
\usepackage{letltxmacro}%


\LetLtxMacro\StandardAppendixBegin\appendices
\LetLtxMacro\StandardAppendixEnd\endappendices%

\renewenvironment{appendices}{%
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
  \section*{\appendixname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}%
  \StandardAppendixBegin%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
  \LetLtxMacro\section\subsection%
}{\StandardAppendixEnd\setcounter{subsection}{0}}%

%% Adding the automatic heading for subappendices%
\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
  \section*{\appendixname}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname}%
  \renewcommand{\setthesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Real Section}

\subsection{A real subsection}


\begin{appendices}%
\subsection{Variablen -- changed appendices environment}
\subsection{Tabellen -- changed appendices environment}
\end{appendices}%



\begin{subappendices}
\subsection{Variablen -- subappendices environment}
\subsection{Tabellen -- subappendices environment}
\end{subappendices}

\section{Another real section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This also works. The only problem I see is, that the formatting of the appendix titles are a bit inconsistent. "Appendices" is formatted as a `\part` and the appendices themselves as subsections. How can I change the formatting of "Appendices" to the section formatting?

Comment: I found an answer to my comment above. See updated question.

Comment: I rather think it is the appendices environment

Comment: The updated answer is perfect! Thank you. One note: To also put "Appendix" into the page headings, put `\pagestyle{myheadings}
  \markright{\appendixname}` into the redefinition of the `appendices` and `subappendices` environments.